# Survivor function in discrete continuous or mixed cases as product integral

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables

I'm reading Kalbfleisch-Prentice "The Statistical Analysis of Failure Time Data" and I don't see in chapter 1.2.3 how the continuous case ($\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$) is deduced. I'm taking the next formula (1.8) and after (omitting the strange product integral notion), $$F(t)=\lim_{r\to \infty}\prod^r_{k=1}\left(1-[\Lambda(u_k)-\Lambda(u_{k-1})]\right)$$ with $0=u_0< u_1<\cdots<u_r=t$ and $\max(u_i-u_{i-1})\to 0$, as the definition of this product integral $P^t_0[1-d\Lambda(u)]$ (I didn't know the term "product integral" at all so far) and inserting $\Lambda(u_k)$ and $\Lambda(u_{(k-1)})$ as given in the 2nd formula of this chapter, $$\Lambda(t)=\int^t_0\lambda_c(u)du + \sum_{j\mid a_j\le t}\lambda_j.$$ I'm able to deduct the discrete case here ($\lambda_c\equiv0$) by finally having $u_k$'s such that at most one $a_j$ is in between $u_{(k-1)}$ and $u_k$ for all $k$, factors are reduced then to $1$'s and $(1-\lambda_j)$'s with $a_j\le t$.

In the continuous case ($\lambda_j=0$ for all $j$) the factors are reduced to $(1-\int^{u_k}_{uk-1}\lambda_c(u)du)$, and I don't see how they multiply to $\exp [-\int^t_0 \lambda_c(u)du]$ in the limit.

9Jan2024: meanwhile I found a simple deduction for a special distribution and a special partition of [0,t]: the exponential distribution with constant hazard $\lambda$: survivor function $F(t)=exp(-\lambda t)$, cumulative hazard function $\Lambda(t)=\lambda t$ and the partition $u_0=0, u_r=t, u_k=\frac kr t, k=1,...,r$. So we have $$\lim_{r\to \infty}\prod^r_{k=1}\left(1-[\Lambda(u_k)-\Lambda(u_{k-1})]\right)=\lim_{r\to \infty}\prod^r_{k=1}\left(1-[\lambda \frac kr t-\lambda \frac {(k-1)}r t]\right)=\lim_{r\to \infty}\prod^r_{k=1}\left(1-\frac {\lambda t}r\right)=\lim_{r\to \infty}\prod^r_{k=1}\left(1-\frac {\lambda t}r\right)^r=exp(-\lambda t)$$ q.e.d

Answer (score 1):

**PART 1** Let $f$ be a function which is continuously differentiable on some interval $[-r,r]$, where $r>0$. Assume also that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$. Since $f'$ is continuous and $f'(0)=1$, for any $\mu>0$, there exists $\nu\in (0,r)$ such that if $|\xi|<\nu$, $|f'(\xi)-1|<\mu$. For this $\nu$, if $|x|\leqslant \nu$, then if $x=0$, we have $f(x)=f(0)=0=1\cdot x$. Otherwise, by the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi$ with $0<|\xi|<|x|$ such that $$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(\xi).$$  Therefore $f(x)=f'(\xi)x$ for any such $x$. Since $0<|\xi|<|x|\leqslant \nu$, $|f'(\xi)-1|<\mu$, and $$|f(x)-x|=|f'(\xi)x-x|=|f'(\xi)-1||x|\leqslant \mu |x|.$$ To summarize: For any $\mu>0$, there exists $\nu\in (0,r)$ such that if $|x|\leqslant \nu$, $$|f(x)-x|\leqslant \mu|x|.$$

**PART 2** We assume that $\lambda$ is such that $M:=\int_0^t |\lambda(w)|dw<\infty$, otherwise integrating it doesn't make sense. In particular, this means that the Borel measure $\mu(A)=\int_A |\lambda(w)|dw$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. This means that for any $\nu>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $0\leqslant u<v\leqslant t$ with $v-u<\delta$, $$\Bigl|\int_u^v \lambda(w)dw\Bigr|\leqslant \int_u^v |\lambda(w)|dw <\nu.$$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Fix $\nu\in (0,r)$ such that if $|x|\leqslant \nu$, then $$|f(x)-x|\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}|x|.$$ Such a $\nu$ exists by Part 1. Fix $\delta>0$ such that for any $0\leqslant u<v\leqslant t$ with $v-u<\delta$, $$\Bigl|\int_u^v \lambda(w)dw\Bigr|\leqslant \nu.$$ By our choice of $\nu$, it follows by taking $x=\int_u^v \lambda(w)dw$ that $$\Bigl|f\Bigl(\int_u^v \lambda(w)dw\Bigr)-\int_u^v \lambda(w)dw\Bigr|\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}\Bigl|\int_u^v \lambda(w)dw\Bigr|\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}\int_u^v |\lambda(w)|dw.$$

Now let $\mathcal{P}=\{u_0,\ldots, u_N\}$ be a partition with $\max_k u_k-u_{k-1}<\delta$. Then for each $k\in\{1,\ldots, N\}$, by the last part of the previous paragraph with $v=u_k$ and $u=u_{k-1}$, we get that $$\Bigl|f\Bigl(\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}\lambda(w)dw\Bigr)-\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}\lambda(w)dw\Bigr| \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}|\lambda(w)|dw.$$

Then for any such $\mathcal{P}$, \begin{align*} \Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^N f\Bigl(\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k} \lambda(w)dw\Bigr)-\int_0^t \lambda(w)dw\Bigr| & = \Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^N \Bigl[f\Bigl(\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k} \lambda(w)dw\Bigr) -\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}\lambda(w)dw\Bigr]\Bigr| \\ & \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^N \Bigl|f\Bigl(\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k} \lambda(w)dw\Bigr) -\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}\lambda(w)dw\Bigr| \\ & \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}|\lambda(w)|dw \\ & = \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}\sum_{k=1}^N\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}|\lambda(w)|dw \\ & = \frac{\varepsilon}{M+1}\int_0^t|\lambda(w)|dw = \varepsilon\cdot \frac{M}{M+1}<\varepsilon.\end{align*}

Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $$\lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^N f\Bigl(\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_k}\lambda(w)dw\Bigr)=\int_0^t \lambda(w)dw.$$

Now we want to apply this with $f(x)=-\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, great idea with $(T)$

Comment: Thinking about convergence, I'm wondering how close to 0 an integral x needs to be for log(1-x) to be as close to -x as I require to prove convergence. For a single summand (1-x), this is achieved by making (uk-u{k-1}) small enough, but this requires more summands to cover [0,t]. So I'm not sure if or how it can be shown that convergence holds

Comment: I've added the details.

Comment: I'm fine with your answer provided λ is continuous (not sure if there are non-continuous cases). The purpose of Kalbfleisch & Prentice's section is to describe the combined case, discrete with continuous. Unfortunately I'm not able to combine correspondingly. Somehow the jumps between uk and u(k-1) must be added to λ(ξk)(uk−u(k−1)) when using your formula (B), but then the convergence to 0 gets lost. There must be another way to show the equality of the survivor function and the product limit for the mixed case

Comment: I've given another solution which works as long as $\lambda$ is intgegrable on $[0,t]$. Continuity of $\lambda$ is not required.

Comment: Actually I did not see your extensive edits. I will rethink it.